# Converting integers to strings

Tags: c++, strings, converting, reinventing-the-wheel, c++03

I drafted a method that I intend to use to convert integers to strings. Is there a way to make it faster? Are there any "simple" changes I could make to improve its performance? This cannot be done with C++11.

```
std::string to_string(int val) {
    static std::string str;
    static std::stringstream ss;
    ss << val;
    ss >> str;
    ss.clear();
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered what would happen if you change the parameter from int to any other type? It still works (as long as there is the appropriate `operator<<` define. So if you make this a template function it should work with all types. Boost did something like this with `boost::lexical_cast<>()`

Answer (score 2):

I have a big concern with this code. It uses local static variables, so this will result in race conditions if used in a multithreaded program.

I assume you did that to improve performance? Constructing the `std::stringstream` could potentially incur some overhead. So having that variable as a static would be understandable if you are sure no race conditions apply. But the `str` string certainly doesn't have to be a local static. Actually, it is not needed at all, since [`stringstream::str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/str/) exists.

I think you have two options here:

Make it thread-safe and cleaner at the cost of some extra object construction every call, which is probably not a big deal:

```
std::string to_string(int val) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << val;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Or, if you need ultimate performance and cannot afford the chance of a memory allocation by `std::stringstream`, then you could use [`sprintf`, `snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) or [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/?kw=itoa). This is a possible implementation, also thread safe, with no statics:

```
std::string to_string(int val) {
    // Buffer size is arbitrary in this example. Could be smaller.
    // 128 is more than enough for any integer number.
    char buffer[128];
    std::snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%i", val);
    return buffer;
}
```

I suggest going with the first one, but if you have a justifiable performance concern, then the second one should perform slightly better.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will stick with the second one. I have no idea how many times that method will be called every second right now.

I forgot about stringstream::str().

Comment: There is no `itoa` in C++. There is [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), though.

Comment: @Cubbi, yes, `itoa` is not standard. It is noted in the link I've added. Didn't mention `std::to_string` because the question is not tagged as C++11, so...